# Exclusion constraint for unique constraint, is there a difference? (bis)

Tags: postgresql, unique-constraint

Assume the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE zoo (
    cage   INTEGER,
    animal TEXT,
);
```

What is the real, effective difference between:

```
ALTER TABLE zoo ADD CONSTRAINT x EXCLUDE USING gist (cage WITH =, animal WITH <>)
```

and:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON zoo(cage, animal)
```

?

I took this example from https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/btree-gist.html and was confused why they are representing this with an `exclude constraint` instead of good-old `unique constraint`. So I am wondering if there is really a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two do different things.

The exclusion constraint is doing just what the documentation says -- it is guaranteeing that a cage has exactly one type of animal.  No lions and sheep in the cage together.

The unique index/constraint says that there are no *duplicate* animals in the cage.  So, a lion and sheep is fine (from that perspective).  But two lions or two sheep is not.  (Of course, the lion and sheep example is likely to quickly result in a satisfied unique constraint).

This type of "exclusion" constraint could be handled using foreign key constraints.  Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE cages (
    CageId serial,
    AnimalType varchar(255)  -- or whatever
);

CREATE TABLE CageAnimals (
    CageAnimalId serial,
    CageId int references Cages(CageId)
    AnimalName varchar(255)
);
```

(The model would be a bit more complicated in real life.)

Comment: I just realized it, I wasn't really thinking I guess. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: My question should actually have been for `=` instead of `<>` for animal. I'll ask a new one later.

Comment: @FranzThey . . . Those might be equivalent, although the types of indexes are different.

Comment: I asked it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47124267/exclusion-constraint-for-unique-constraint-is-there-a-difference