# Exclusion constraint for unique constraint, is there a difference?

Tags: postgresql, unique-constraint

Assume the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE zoo (
    cage   INTEGER,
    animal TEXT,
);
```

Is there a real, effective difference between:

```
ALTER TABLE zoo ADD CONSTRAINT x EXCLUDE USING gist (cage WITH =, animal WITH =)
```

and:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON zoo(cage, animal)
```

?

Comment: [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html#sql-createtable-exclude): "*If all of the specified operators test for equality, this is equivalent to a UNIQUE constraint, although an ordinary unique constraint will be faster*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: it is not mentioned explicitly: does `&&` also tests for equality? `EXCLUDE USING gist ( person_id WITH =, tstzrange(valid_from, valid_till, '[)' ) WITH && )`

Comment: `&&` is the "overlaps" operator: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: but it also forces uniques

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I read this on the blog of the author of the exclude constraints:

[Exclusion Constraints are generalized SQL UNIQUE](http://thoughts.davisjeff.com/2010/09/25/exclusion-constraints-are-generalized-sql-unique/)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS a;
CREATE TABLE a(i int);
ALTER TABLE a ADD EXCLUDE (i WITH =);
```

*That is identical to a UNIQUE constraint on a.i, except that it uses the Exclusion Constraints mechanism; it even uses a normal BTree to enforce it. The performance will be slightly worse because of some micro-optimizations for UNIQUE constraint, but only slightly, and the performance characteristics should be the same (it’s just as scalable). Most importantly, it behaves the same under high concurrency as a UNIQUE constraint, so you don’t have to worry about excessive locking. If one person inserts 5, that will prevent other transactions from inserting 5 concurrently, but will not interfere with a transaction inserting 6.*

This more or less answers the question.